# NextJs : Your `getStaticProps` function did not return an object

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am making a web application with NextJs. In the page I need to fetch an api to get data and display it. But it compiles I have got an error.

The error is : `` Error: Your `getStaticProps` function did not return an object. Did you forget to add a `return`? ``

And there is my function :

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(ApiLinks.players.all)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => response.data.teamMembers)
  
        const responsePlayers = res.players;
        const responseStaff = res.staff;

        return {
            props: {
                responsePlayers,
                responseStaff,
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because getStaticProps must return props it's better to add try-catch outside of it, so props can have data or not :

sth like this :

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  let props = {};
  try {
    const res = await fetch(ApiLinks.players.all)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => response.data.teamMembers);

    const responsePlayers = res.players;
    const responseStaff = res.staff;
    props = {
      responsePlayers,
      responseStaff,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }

  return {
    props,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function seems to be fine. Just check by console log whether both of the responsePlayers and responseStaff are object or not and if not try returning then like this :

```
return{
   props:{
      responsePlayers:responsePlayers,
      responseStaff:responseStaff
   }
}
```

also add this in the catch

```
return{
     props:null
}
```

and check if props is null or not in the above component.